# lazy loading - overview and estimated improvements?

Tags: reactjs

A simplified description to implement lazy loading would be to rewrite routes imports like this:

```
const Users = lazy(()=> import("Pages/Users"));
```

This would ensure that Users.js is only loaded when it's rendered.  So what happens exactly if a React app has 100 components defined for routing and the routing imports are *not* configured for lazy loading?  For example, does this simply mean that the initial render of the first component of the app has the overhead of loading the files of all of the other additional components?  Would any events/lifecycles also get triggered for each of the additionally loaded components? If so then which specific events get triggered?  Also, is the same or similar overhead encountered when loading subsequent routed components in the app after the initial rendered routed component?  If an app has 100 routed components and each component has 1K lines of code then what kind of performance improvements would you expect to see by converting the app routing to use a lazy loading implementation?

Answer (score 0):

Lazy loading in general means dont do anything until your'e needed,
What you would see is that your js file downloaded if you inspect the initial page, will be smaller, then when you reach a page that was lazy, you will see a small chunk of the JS loaded for this component.
This means that the page will go up faster when users enter, but pages will load slower when reached.
The alternative of not lazy loading means, everything is loaded, hence initial request is bigger, so page will load slower, but transition between components will be smoother.
After loading a component, the component will be in memory and you dont need to load it again, this wouldnt affect life cycles of component that are not being used.
So a component that is loaded but isnt used, will not get useEffect and all of that.